# Row is not resizing on ios with xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am using a list view in xamarin forms which will expand the row on row tap and collapse the row if the row is expanded.The logic works fine in android but i am getting problem with IOS.Is there any way to resize the height on ios

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you can share the code you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Instead use stack layout and toggle the visibility of stack layout on tap.

Comment: Incredible, but I had to do this to make it work on iOS. Makes me think these Collection Views are not ready for this type of Use Cases.